# Junits getting failed during maven build?

Tags: spring, maven, junit, maven-3, junit4

I need a small information on Junits when testing with Maven and eclipse.
When I am running test cases in eclipse getting passed. But the same test cases when I run through maven getting failed. I am using Spring with Junit. After testInsertClassUnit executed successfully.While executing flushHibernateSession() of testInsertMap() method it is hanging.

Java Files:

```
 class AbstractTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
 /**
    * Flushes the SessionFactory currently associated to TransactionManager bean.
    */
   protected void changeTransactionDataSource(SessionFactory pSessionFactory) {
      HibernateTransactionManager vTransactionManager = (HibernateTransactionManager) this.applicationContext.getBean(
            "transactionManagerHibernate");
      vTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(pSessionFactory);
      vTransactionManager.setDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(pSessionFactory));

   }

}

    public class AbstractTest extends AbstractTest {

   private BefClassUnit mBefClassUnit;
   private SessionFactory mSessionFactory;


   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("sessionFactoryCorporateBaseData")
   public void setSessionFactoryCorporateBaseData(SessionFactory pSessionFactory) {
      this.mSessionFactory = pSessionFactory;
   }

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("dataSourceBatch")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource pDataSource) { 

        super.setDataSource(pDataSource);
    }

   @BeforeTransaction
      public void onSetUpBeforeTransaction() throws Exception {
      changeTransactionDataSource(mSessionFactory);
   }

  @Before
  public void onSetUpInTransaction() throws Exception {
      deleteFromTable(ClassUnitColumns.TABLE_NAME);
   }

   /**
    * Test insert(ClassUnit pClassUnit).
    */
  @Test
   public void testInsertClassUnit() {

      ClassUnit vClassUnit = getClassUnit("BU", "STO", "999", new DateTime(), new DateTime());

      try {
         getBefClassUnit().insert(vClassUnit);
         flushHibernateSession(mSessionFactory);
         assertEquals(1, countRowsInTable(ClassUnitColumns.TABLE_NAME));

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace(System.err);
         fail(e.getMessage());
      }
   }

   /**
    * Test insert(ClassUnitMap pClassUnitMap).
    */
  @Test
   public void testInsertMap() {

      ClassUnitMap vClassUnitMap = new ClassUnitMap();

      vClassUnitMap.putClassUnit(getClassUnit("BU", "STO", "999", new DateTime(), new DateTime()));
      vClassUnitMap.putClassUnit(getClassUnit("GR", "RU", "AUW", new DateTime(), new DateTime()));

      try {
         getBefClassUnit().insert(vClassUnitMap);
         flushHibernateSession(mSessionFactory);
         assertEquals(2, countRowsInTable(ClassUnitColumns.TABLE_NAME));
      } catch (Exception e) {
         fail();
      }
   }

   @Resource(name="befClassUnit")
   public void setBefClassUnit(BefClassUnit unit) {
      mBefClassUnit = unit;
   }

}
```

Comment: This usually happens with badly written tests that are somehow not atomic, and leave leftovers in memory that interfere with the following tests. It's impossible, however, to give a more concrete answer without seeing some code.

Comment: Got the below error:     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (unit-tests) on project rixjavacommon: There are test failures.

Comment: You'll have to share the code if you want us to try and help you. It's just impossible to answer with so little details.

Comment: When I tried to run the same junits from eclipse i got the same issue. I cannot post all the code but gave u the code,where the code is not getting executed.

Comment: This time i run whole junits from eclipse.  What I observed during calling flushHibernateSession() of testInsertMap() it is hanging even not throwing nay error also.Can u please let me know where it is hanging.